# Clear input fields below input changed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have the following HTML with several input fields. Depending on what input field you modify I need to clear the rest which are below the one being modified. **Is there a function like nextAll in Angular**?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let requiredItem of modifyOrderAddressViewModel.required; let i = index">

        <ion-item *ngIf="requiredItem.noSelectable">
            <ion-label stacked>{{ requiredItem.title }}</ion-label>
            <ion-input
                (ionBlur)="onChangeStreetNr(requiredItem)"
                (ionFocus)="checkInput()"
                [disabled]="requiredItem.fieldType === ADDRESS_OPTIONS.POSTAL_CODE"
                type="text" 
                maxlength="5"
                [(placeholder)]="requiredItem.placeHolder" 
                [(ngModel)]="requiredItem.value">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the index of `ngFor`. Just use it when values are changing

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let requiredItem of modifyOrderAddressViewModel.required; let i = index">
  <ion-item *ngIf="requiredItem.noSelectable">
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="requiredItem.value" (ngModelChange)="clearAllFrom(i)">
      </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
clearAllFrom(startIndex) {
    for(let i = startIndex + 1, e = modifyOrderAddressViewModel.required.length; i < e; ++i) {
      modifyOrderAddressViewModel.required[i].value = '';
    }
}
```